# Find the SPECIFIC records in the table which have white space on second place only?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have record table for xyz . There is a column like

`0025336625`
`0036625336`
`9986698852`
**`0 22336652`**
**`1 32236633`**
`9333265556`
**`8 44555223`**

So I only need these records fetch from the table which is in Bold only .

Comment: The question is unclear - what if the record has a space in second position and also an additional space somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use substr for filter the column

```
select * 
from my_table 
where substr(my_column, 2, 1 ) = ' ';
```